# CMD: echo text when folder exist

Tags: if-statement, cmd

Im using below code to remove folders with names in the Remove.txt

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "filelist=Remove.txt"

for /f "delims=;" %%b in (%filelist: =3%) do if exist "c:\%%b" RD /S/Q "c:\%%b"
```

Is there any way to display some text by `echo` when folder exist and in the same time execute `RD`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&` to join commands and execute them on the same line.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "filelist=Remove.txt"

for /f "delims=;" %%b in (%filelist: =3%) do if exist "c:\%%b" ECHO %%b & RD /S/Q "c:\%%b"
```

Or we can use () for multi line code

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "filelist=Remove.txt"

for /f "delims=;" %%b in (%filelist: =3%) do if exist "c:\%%b" (
ECHO "%%b avaialble to delete"
RD /S/Q "c:\%%b"
)
```

Comment: Using `&` makes code more clearer if there are only two lines to execute. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test but something like this should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "filelist=Remove.txt"

for /f "delims=;" %%b in (%filelist: =3%) do if exist "c:\%%b" (
    echo "%%b exists"
    RD /S/Q "c:\%%b"
)
```